# How to set Settings view level on MenuBarExtra app in SwiftUI project?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, nswindow

Here's the sample code:

```
struct MainScene: Scene {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup(id: "mainscene") {
            Button("close") {
                NSApplication.shared.keyWindow?.close()
            }
            .task {
                NSApp.windows.first?.close()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Demo: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        MainScene()
        Settings {
          SettingView()
        }
        MenuBarExtra("Menu Bar", systemImage: "swift") {
            Button("Perferences...") {
                NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showSettingsWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
            }
            Divider()
            Button("Quit") {
                NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)
            }.keyboardShortcut("q")
        }
    }
}
```

When I clicked the *Perferences* button, the setting view always popup behind other application's window.

I tried some ways like set all windows' level to `.float`:

```
for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
    window.level = .floating
}
```

In this way, when I close the Setting window, the MenuBarExtra button also disappears, but the process still running in background.

Answer (score 0):

```
for window in NSApplication.shared.windows {
    if window.title == "Demo Settings" {
        window.level = .floating
    }
}
```

Fix it by adding a if statement to detect if it's the Setting window. If not, the MenuBarExtra will disappear (I don't know if it's a bug).

Answer (score 0):

Activate the application first, then send the action to show the settings window.

```swift
Button("Perferences...") {
    NSApp.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)
    NSApp.sendAction(Selector(("showSettingsWindow:")), to: nil, from: nil)
}
```